# How to get an attributes value within a XSLT template parameter?

Tags: xslt, xpath, apply-templates

I am calling apply-templates as follows:

```
<xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:with-param name="pWeight" select="@layoutWeight * $pContentWidth" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

I am trying to access the `layoutWeight` attribute value of the child element to which apply-templates is acting on.  However, the computation is always evaluating as empty, even though the child items have a numeric value for `layoutWeight` and `pContentWidth` is also a numeric value.

How do I access the `layoutWeight` attribute of the child element apply-templates is acting on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` attribute on a `with-param` is evaluated relative to the surrounding context, not relative to each node on which templates are being applied. One way to accomplish what you are trying to do is wrap the `apply-templates` in a `for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
    <xsl:with-param name="pWeight" select="@layoutWeight * $pContentWidth" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The other option would be to just pass the `$pContentWidth` parameter into the `apply-templates` and have the template(s) themselves access the `@layoutWidth` and perform the computation.